# How to update/overwrite the json metadata in GCS using react

Tags: reactjs, json, google-cloud-storage, metadata, updates

I researched on how to edit the metadata and found this:

```
curl -X PATCH --data-binary @JSON_FILE_NAME \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o/OBJECT_NAME"
```

Tried

```
updateMetadata = (bucketname,filename,newId) => {
 const { token } = this.props;
 return fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o/filename', {
  'method': 'PATCH',
  'headers': new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': token
  }),
  'body': JSON.stringify({
    'metadata': { 'id': newId }
   })
 })
 .then( response => {return response.json()})
 .then( res => { return res })
}
```

The output for this one should update thr metadata id to newId. Key is id then vakue should be newId. I also researched abt the use of new FormData() but I am quite unfamiliar with it. This is also my reference so far: *https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#prereq-rest*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with `data` instead of `body` and using `Buffer`

```
updateMetadata = (newId) => {
 const { token } = this.props;
 return fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o/OBJECT_NAME', {
  'method': 'PATCH',
  'headers': new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': token
  }),
  'data': Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
    'metadata': { 'id': newId }
   }))
 })
 .then( response => {return response.json()})
 .then( res => { return res })
}
```

Comment: Already edited my question. But it still wont work